# Did Hillary Clinton say this quote about Donald Trump and equal pay?

Tags: quotes, donald-trump, hillary-clinton

A [meme on 9gag](http://9gag.com/gag/aM95GE1) says:

[image]

> "He [Trump] doesn't think women deserve equal pay unless they do as good a
> job as men."
>
> Hillary Clinton 09/26/2016

Is this true that Clinton actually said that?

May I know what's her motive of saying that? I mean the claim make it looks like Hillary is against free market meritocracy for example. Is it what she really means?

Comment: Did you try Googling this? Both the Clinton and Trump quotes are pretty widely reported.

Comment: I couldn't find it

Comment: I rolled back some edits that asked for an explanation of Clinton's policy position on equal rights. This is off-topic here, because it isn't about a specific claim. Try Politics.SE.

Comment: I've put this question on hold to spot the edit war. The additional questions being added are not part of a claim and are not on-topic.

Answer (score 16):

The first Trump-Clinton Presidential Debate on 26 September 2016 was widely watched and reported.

The [Washington Post provided a transcript](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2016/09/26/the-first-trump-clinton-presidential-debate-transcript-annotated/):

> CLINTON: You know, he tried to switch from looks to stamina. But this is a man who has called women pigs, slobs and dogs, and someone who has said pregnancy is an inconvenience to employers, who has said...
>
> TRUMP: I never said that.
>
> CLINTON: .... women don't deserve equal pay unless they do as good a job as men.
>
> TRUMP: I didn't say that.

So the meme is not word for word accurate, but approximates what Clinton said in the debate.

The context behind the quote is provided by [FactCheck](http://www.factcheck.org/2016/06/clintons-equal-pay-claim/) (via [their fact checking on the debate](http://www.factcheck.org/2016/09/factchecking-the-first-debate/)).

Comment: It is not only for word inaccurate, it completely misrepresents what she has said by omitting the "(...) as if we aren’t already." part.

Comment: @tomasz while I agree that's probably what she meant, I'm not seeing that in the transcript.

Comment: @tomasz Wait, what do you mean?

Comment: @tomasz I just watched that part of the debate several times.  I'm not quite sure what you are referring too.  Could you expound on how it misrepresents what she said?

Comment: @tomasz Ohhh, you're referring to when she said something similar in a speech on June 21st (not the debate on Sep. 26) that could also be used as the source of the quote.

Comment: Ah, if she had intended to continue with "...as if we weren't already", her quote would make much more sense.

Comment: Is this a common misreading? Can I make it clearer? She did say something very similar to the meme in the first debate, which seems odd at first blush. If you look at the context link, you can see what she was presumably trying to say, but whether *that* is true or not, I am leaving for FactCheck.

Comment: This is not a meme. It's an image with some text on it. A meme would be like a running gag of sorts.

Comment: Hi @progo: Welcome to language, where word meanings change. [Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9GAG#Content). Note that this was picture itself that did not originate on 9Gag, but was transformed there (with a logo) and copied to other sites, so it fits under "Internet meme", even Dawkins is uncomforable with the word being hijacked.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Red indigo troops ran around the lonely tree, quickly. Evergreen when it spreads for which into space with a crying laser..... Oh, hey, you got that, right? Sorry but word meanings change! A language is a set of words used commonly by a bunch of people for mutual understanding. Sure, language eventually evolves, but it's still important to use the "right" words when you can, as that is literally the entire point of having a language. By the way, have a read of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice

Comment: Let's take the discussion on English language [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46784/discussion-on-answer-by-oddthinking-did-hillary-clinton-say-this-quote-about-don).

Comment: This answer would be better summarizing the context: they had previous said things on the subject which made sense while in the debate they interrupted each other: Clinton that women already did as good a job as men but on average had lower pay, and Trump that interfering with individuals' pay could lead to poor performers being paid as much as good performers

Comment: I would like to add an answer. The meme is wrong or seriously misrepresent what Clinton said. Clinton claims that women do as good as a job as men. So it's not like she insist that they deserve equal pay. https://www.factcheck.org/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/www.factcheck.org/2016/06/clintons-equal-pay-claim//index.html_gzip

Comment: @J.Chang: yes, that link is included in the last line.